# using cgo to hook syscall "fork"

Tags: linux, go, cgo, ld-preload

I'm trying to hook the fork syscall in Linux using Go.

```golang
package main

/*
#include <unistd.h>
*/
import "C"

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"

    "github.com/rainycape/dl"
)

func main() {}

//export fork
func fork() C.pid_t {
    lib, err := dl.Open("libc", 0)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    defer lib.Close()
    var old_fork func() C.pid_t
    lib.Sym("fork", &old_fork)
    return old_fork()
}
```

When I compile and run as `LD_PRELOAD`, Panic occurs

```
panic: reflect.MakeFunc: value of type `int32` is not assignable to type main._Ctype_int
```

Comment: It looks like this `dl` package wants you to use type `int` for the return type of `fork`, rather than `C.pid_t`. (That said, sticking a hook in front of `fork` is going to be problematic.)

Comment: You can't fork a process with the Go runtime, so using Go to hook `fork` is not going to work correctly.

Answer (score -1):

You should set some directives for running that. Please take a look at its official documentation. [using cgo - Golang official doc](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/)